# Capturing key pressed in free pascal?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I try the following, to capture the "Esc" key:

```
procedure Tform1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    KeyPreview := True;
end;      

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: char);
begin
  if Key = #27 then
    begin
      btnCloseClick(Sender);
    end;
end;
```

But Interrupted place a point to debug, and never invoked the method

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It works for me. What is your target system? It is only part of some bigger application or just that simple example?

Comment: Works properly on simple test app for me. Provide more info: target OS, versions of FPC/Lazarus, is there any other code/controls on the your form...

Comment: The method must be connected to the onkeypress event of the form? Just declaring it is not enough.

Answer (score -1):

try the event UTFKeyPress instead:

```
procedure TForm1.FormUTF8KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var UTF8Key: TUTF8Char);
begin
  if UTF8Key = #27 then
    btnCloseClick(Sender);
end;
```